# Odd crash problem

Tags: windows-7, crash, notification-area

I have three problems:

1. My computer sometimes crashes (its happened maybe 4 times in the 8 months I've had it), such that my optical mouse and keyboard appear to lose power (their lights shut off). I believe the display freezes, too, as the clock does not change.
2. The last time this happened, when I started back up again, I couldn't see most of the icons in my system tray:

   [image]
3. I don't think this is related, but does anyone know how to get rid of that Test Mode thing? I enabled it for something for work, and now I can't seem to get rid of it.

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise. I have an i7 920 @ 3.6GHz, 6GB RAM, and two striped Intel SSDs.

Also, when the last crash happened, it seemed to reset my system clock, and now that I look at it, most of my BIOS settings (my mulitplier is now set to 12x, gotta fix that).

Can anyone offer any insight into these problems?

Update:

This can't be good. I rebooted to fix the multiplier, and when I did, it was back up to 3.6GHz, and more concerning, my system clock was off again. It was an hour fast. The date was still correct, though. Here's what CPU-Z is now showing:

[image]

Also, the system tray icons are back. I don't know that that's necessarily a good thing. They seem to come and go every other reboot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bcdedit /set testsigning off` at an elevated command prompt should disable test mode.

As for the strange lockups, you might double check that all of your USB devices are functioning properly - I recently had an issue where an IR receiver would periodically cause all USB ports on my system to shut off. Unexplained freezes can also be a sign of a bad overclock (i.e. overheating or the chip simply can't handle it). If you're continuing to get the freezes, I would step back on the numbers a bit. When you rebooted to fix your multiplier, are you sure the 12X wasn't simply Intel's SpeedStep slowing the processor down when idle? 12X is what my i7-920 idles at. As for BIOS settings being reset, my motherboard also resets back to the last known good defaults if it fails to shut down properly, in the event that an overclock failed and would otherwise leave you unable to enter the BIOS and set it back manually. Might you be experiencing similar behavior?